# CSS color not being applied

Tags: html, css, colors

I have CSS:

```
.homepagebox {color: #2F2561 !important; margin-bottom: 16px !important;}
```

and `<p class="homepagebox"><strong>Home Loans</strong></p>`

but the colour is not being applied.

Live [page here](http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/).

Comment: There is no class called `.homepagebox` when you inspect. Check your stylesheet again and make sure you have added the code.

Comment: Yes, you have used class .homepagebox but did not declare in your stylesheet.

Comment: May be you have not attached stylesheet to page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the

```
.homepagebox {color: #2F2561 !important; margin-bottom: 16px !important;}
```

right over the line

```
.box {text-align: center;}
```

in the style.css file and it worked.